# Suggestion for FullCalendar event removal UI

Tags: events, fullcalendar

I have my fullCalendar functioning well, however, I need to allow the users to remove events from the calendar.  I can use the clickEvent method to bring up a confirmation window with a "do you want to remove" message.  But this seems kind of clunky.  Is there a better UI way of removing events?

Answer (score 4):

Google calendar uses a [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) on click that offers "edit event details" and "delete". At first I didn't like sending users to a different "event details page" but after thinking about this for awhile it is a really good way to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is always safer to ask for a confirm before removing something.

Anyway you can customize the rendering of the event using the [eventRender callback](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)
In particular you can:

- attach custom markup to render an X image that when clicked will ajax call a delete function
- you can attach other jQuery plugins to reproduce exactly the qTip effect

Have a look at the link for more details. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Poking around I found something like Lorenzo's suggestion: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/attachmentText?id=210&aid=-166241222149182113&name=hoverDeleteButton.txt&token=b07e24289819cd647c3d81d05e99ce7f This works great.

Comment: Geat! But be aware of making it hard to click accidentally. e.g. use big enough delete icon. Honestly, as an UX, I would inform user in modal box. Remember deleting stuff is critical.